# Error with adding two strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following error:

> jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 The specified value "24.164.83" is not a valid
> number. The value must match to the following regular expression:
> -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

#### Code

```
var grossTotal = netPrice * vatTotal // Is OK - it multiplies values
```

but

```
var grossTotal = netPrice + vatTotal // It makes this error -
```

it doesn’t sum.

Comment: One is a string, other one is a number or both are strings. Try debugging your code, with given info you're not going to get much help.

Comment: use `var grossTotal=netPrice*1+vatTotal*1`

Comment: check type of both variables im sure that they are not same type thats why

Comment: What are `netTotal` and `vatTotal`? Where are they defined? How are they computed?

Comment: The problem is very likely in the values of the variables, and so in the lines before the (very short) code sample you're giving.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to produce a number from a string is prepend with +

```
var grossTotal= +netPrice + +vatTotal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
var netPrice = 1.432;
var vatTotal = 14.423;
var grossTotal = parseFloat(netPrice) + parseFloat(vatTotal)// Change according to data type of netPrice and/or vatTotal
console.log(grossTotal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with type conversion:

```
 var answer = parseInt(netPrice ) + parseInt(vatTotal);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, First format value using `parseFloat`

```js
 var netPrice = 2.3777;
 var vatTotal = 1.3777;
 var grossTotal = parseFloat(netPrice ) + parseFloat(vatTotal);
 console.log(grossTotal);
```

```js
     var netPrice = 2;
     var vatTotal = 1;
     var grossTotal = parseInt(netPrice ) + parseInt(vatTotal);
     console.log(grossTotal);
```

For more information about `parseFloat`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp